# Find places in the route on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to find the Places in the driving route in which i'm traveling or want to see the places in the route between two places.

Say,I'm Going From Place A to Place D Which Has 2 Markers B,C As shown in [image: Figure],

My question is How to get the details of places with-in 3 Km (Location C) radius in between source A and destination D,

Please help me.

Comment: official docs :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Comment: Your question sounds like this feature request in the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829074. Feel free to add star to it to express your interest.